# Contagem regressiva de uma lista passando em um if

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma lista de email de um banco de dados, mas só quero mandar para os que estão marcados com `checkbox`. Se marquei 10, quero que diminua um, cada vez que passar pelo if, e quando passar mostrar os número e quando terminar mostrar uma mensagem.

Por exemplo: marquei os dez e clico em enviar, pode ser em um modal, mostrar os números diminuindo e depois uma mensagem como concluído.

Qualquer ideia ou dica é bem vinda.

Comment: apenas um comentário sobre o "UI": Esse tipo de UI é muito anos 90, onde era preciso bastante tempo a enviar um email, hoje em dia à ferramentas async para enviar e API's que levam apenas 1 segundo a enviar um email... Envie logo para todos os emails (1 unico email com `bcc` da lista é suficiente) e mostra a página *n emails enviados*... para seleccionar todos os `checkbox` marcados, com jQuery é simples: [`$("checkbox:checked")`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Comment: primeiro seria interessante você informar que tecnologia está usando no Server-Side, Java, .NET, NodeJS, etc. Em todo caso, se estiver enviando uma "Mala Direta", onde cada e-mail é personalizado para o destinatario, você pode enviar a lista de emails, o servidor retornar um ticket e continuar o processamento dos mesmos, então você pode usar este ticket para verificar o andamento do processo. uma outra opção, seria o servidor notificar o browser através de um WebSocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente usar `setInterval`para aplicar a redução nos valores de acordo com o tempo e, após o termino, limpar a execução:

```
var emailsToSend = 10;
var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  counter.innerHTML = emailsToSend;
  if (emailsToSend === 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);   
  }
  emailsToSend--;
}, 150);
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/haskellcamargo/gs2proL7/

Comment: já tenho o sistema que envia, é somente tipo um contador pra mostrar em uma `div` ou modal quando o sistema passa pelo if. Mesmo assim obrigado.